# Why do Java array declarations use curly brackets?

Tags: java, arrays, declaration, curly-braces

I would like to know why Java array declarations use curly brackets as opposed to the standard parenthesis. As illustrated here. I imagine this may take further understanding of curly brackets in general, but this specifically is on my agenda right now.

```
Object[] tableHeaders = {"Cars","Trucks","Tacos"};
```

This is correct, as opposed to.

```
Object[] tableHeaders = ("Cars","Trucks","Tacos");
```

Comment: If you're looking for an official justification from James Gosling, I think you're out of luck. It's more or less a standard from the world of mathematics. I don't think this question has a definitive answer.

Comment: @yock - how are braces "a standard from the world of mathematics"? In the usual math notation braces represent (unordered) sets, while (ordered) sequences are set off by parens.

Comment: I was also wondering why are arrays not declared like `Object[] ar=["Cars", "Trucks", "Tacos"];`. For first part of your answer "why?" to attract more people to initially develop it who have "C" programming background. I am sure James Gosling was one of them. You can just leave out the further understanding of curly braces in general because compilers parse language based on states.

Comment: Just taking my cues from Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Curly brackets usually denotes sets and ensembles while parenthesis usually denotes parameters in C-like languages.

A long time ago, people got used to having [this kind of convention with C](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html). I'm pretty sure that it works this way in Java to keep some kind of syntax consistency with older languages.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the C syntax for array initialization: `char const * tableHeaders[] = {"Cars","Trucks","Tacos"};`  I'm sure this more than anything else is the reason.

Comment: It's definitely inspired by C. But arrays are sequences (order matters), not sets or ensembles. In most mathematical notation systems, sequences are typically delimited by parentheses.

Answer (score 8):

I can't say *why* James Gosling et al chose this particular alternative ...

However, using round brackets instead of curly brackets would create a serious ambiguity problem for the Java grammar.  Consider the following example:

```
Object[] tableHeaders = ("Cars");
```

Do the round brackets denote an array constructor, or are they part of the normal expression expression syntax?

Now it would be possible to come up with some complicated precedence rules to cover this, but that makes life difficult for both programmers and compiler writers.

(At the grammatical level, a Java parser needs to deal with ambiguity in:

```
VariableInitializer:
    ArrayInitializer
    Expression
```

In the example above, `("Cars")` matches both the ArrayInitializer and Expression productions ... if you use round brackets for array initializers.  Deciding which is correct meaning would require looking at the declared variable type ... followed by context sensitive parsing of the VariableInitializer.  Nasty.)

I'd say they made the right choice in not using round brackets for array initializers.

---

Square brackets won't work either.  Consider trying to explain this ...

```
... = new Object[]["Cars"];  // 1-D array
```

versus

```
... = new Object[21][];      // 2-D array
```

versus

```
... = new Object[][];        // is that 1-D or 2-D?
```

Answer (score 1):

In most Algol-based programming languages, which are the most widely-used languages, arrays are declared using the curly braces.

Comment: You mean in most Algol-inspired languages. Not in Perl, Fortran, Cobol, Lisp, ....